# Передача обьекта после выполнения REST запроса Spring

Tags: java, android, spring

Имеется сервер, с которого можно получить JSON в виде списка объектов класса Place. При запросе я успешно получаю необходимый список, однако когда я пытюась его передать (listOfPlaces = places;) в основной класс (список listOfPlaces) в начале кода, ничего не происходит. Как это лучше сделать? Я понимаю, что скорее всего я не в том месте делаю передачу из HttpRequestTask, но не могу понять, где и как (пытался сделать get и set внутри него, такой же эффект)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    List<Place> listOfPlaces;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new HttpRequestTask().execute(); }

private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Example> {
    @Override
    protected Example doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "****";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Example example = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Example.class);
            return example;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Example example) {
        List<Place> places = example.getEmbedded().getPlace();
        for (Place place : places) {
            Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(place.getPlaceId()));
        }
        listOfPlaces = places;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ничего не происходит` -- а что должно происходить и где в приведенном коде это что-то происходит?

Comment: @post_zeew грубо говоря, я надеялся передать список places из HttpRequestTask в MainActivity, однако как раз *ничего не происходит

Comment: Скорее всего вы пытаетесь обратиться к данным до того, как они получены.

Comment: @post_zeew вы были правы, данные тогда еще не были получены. Прощу прощения за непонятный код, он писался в 3 часа ночи. В оригинале я запрашивал список в onCreate() сразу после выполнения new HttpRequestTask().execute();, а они не успели тогда еще подгрузиться (запросил их по клику на кнопку, всё заработало). 

В связи с этим можете ли посоветать способ, как реализовать какую-нибудь задержку перед тем, как я к ним попробую обратиться к ним (несколько секунд, ибо данных не очень много), чтобы они успели скачаться? Спасибо!

Comment: Метод `onPostExecute` выполняется после загрузки данных. Здесь Вы можете начинать работать с ними.